# SQL Server BI, Reporting Tool

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reporting

I have a requirement where our client wants to build reports using reporting tool with following are some requirements:

1. The tool should generate the report which can be viewed on mobile and web.
2. The tool should allow ad-hoc/custom reporting
3. The tool should able to connect MS SQL Server 2019 warehouse database

Does SSRS or MS Power BI can be used for the above requirements or there are any other better tool which can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! both SSRS and PBI can be used for your case. There are lot other tools in the market who can connect to MS SQL Server 2019 warehouse database, so those 2 are not the only options. As a result, for choosing the platform, you can consider these below-

1. If you choose SSRS or MS PBI, all will be in single platform - Microsoft.
2. Check the licensing in different platform
3. Customization option
4. Community
5. Is there any client requirements?
6. Check the distribution/sharing options of report among end users in different platform.

With experience of developing reports in Crystal Report, SAP BO, Pentaho and Power BI - I can advice to chose PBI as it is easy to develop and powerful enough to meet any complex requirement.

Comment: Thanks R_R! The development platform is Microsoft (Windows), however the report can be published to be viewed on Web and Mobile platform. I was thinking of suggesting PBI

Comment: PBI support reports to deploy in web (Power BI service) where from you can view them using web or mobile. You can also embed the report to your own website using iFrame.